# Scrape <script> tag in PHP Goutte

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping, goutte

I am scraping a website using PHP [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte), but I need some informations that are indicated only in a script tag in the following way:

```html
<script>
player.qualityselector({
        sources: [
          { format: 'auto', src: "xxx.example.com", type: 'video/mp4'},
                        { format: '1080p WEB-DL', src: "xxx.example.com", type: 'video/mp4'},
                          { format: '720p WEB-DL', src: "xxx.example.com", type: 'video/mp4'},
                          { format: '480p WEB-DL', src: "xxx.example.com4", type: 'video/mp4'},
                          { format: '360p WEB-DL', src: "xxx.example.com", type: 'video/mp4'},
                          { format: '240p WEB-DL', src: "xxx.example.com", type: 'video/mp4'},
      ],
      });
</script>
```

I need the src of each one, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions.

**Example**

```php
$page_content = <<<EOF
<script>
player.qualityselector({
        sources: [
          { format: 'auto', src: "xxx.example.com", type: 'video/mp4'},
                        { format: '1080p WEB-DL', src: "xxx.example.com", type: 'video/mp4'},
                          { format: '720p WEB-DL', src: "xxx.example.com", type: 'video/mp4'},
                          { format: '480p WEB-DL', src: "xxx.example.com4", type: 'video/mp4'},
                          { format: '360p WEB-DL', src: "xxx.example.com", type: 'video/mp4'},
                          { format: '240p WEB-DL', src: "xxx.example.com", type: 'video/mp4'},
      ],
      });
</script>
EOF;

preg_match_all('/src:\s"(.*)"/', $page_content, $match);
$result = $match[1];
print_r($result);
```

Output

```php
Array
(
    [0] => xxx.example.com
    [1] => xxx.example.com
    [2] => xxx.example.com
    [3] => xxx.example.com4
    [4] => xxx.example.com
    [5] => xxx.example.com
)
```